# Let $E:y^2=x(x-a)(x-b)(a,b\in \Bbb{Q})$ be an elliptic curve. What is $\#E_d(\Bbb{Q})_{tor}$?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties, torsion-groups

Let $E:y^2=x(x-a)(x-b)(a\neq b\in \Bbb{Q})$ be an elliptic curve　over a field of rational numbers.

Let $d\in \Bbb{Z}$ be a square free integer and $E_d:dy^2=x(x-a)(x-b)$ be a quadratic twist of $E$.

It is clear that $\#E_d(\Bbb{Q})[2]=4$ because $y=0$ has 3 roots. .

My question is, what is $\#E_d(\Bbb{Q})_{tor}$ ?

If $\#E_d(\Bbb{Q})_{tor}=\#E_d(\Bbb{Q})[2]・・・①$ holds, it's easy, but I don't have confident about ①.

This one is related https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76413/torsion-subgroups-in-families-of-twists-of-elliptic-curves question in Mathoverflow, but this page mainly deals with odd part, not $2-$part.

Comment: In general, if $n = \prod p_i^{n_i}$, then $\#E(\mathbb Q)[n] = \prod\#E(\mathbb Q)[p_i^{n_i}]$. Moreover, quadratic twisting doesn't change the size of the $2$-torsion group. In any case, all but finitely many twists will have $E_d(\mathbb Q)_{tor} = E_d(\mathbb Q)[2]$

Comment: @Mathmo$123$. Thank you very much. For what $d$,  ①: $E_d(\Bbb{Q})_{tor}=E_d(\Bbb{Q})[2]$  does not hold ?

Comment: It depends on $E$. But lets say you replace $E$ with whichever $E_d$ has maximal torsion in the family. Then it should be easier to figure out

Comment: @Mathmo$123$ Thank you very much. Can you give a proof or some reference for the fact that all but finitely many twists have $E_d(\Bbb{Q})_{tor}=E_d(\Bbb{Q})[2]$ ?

Comment: For each $p$ consider $E[p]$ as a $G_{\mathbb Q}$ module. $E_d[p](\mathbb Q)\ne 0$ if and only if $E_d[p]$ has a trivial subrepresentation. But $E_d[p]\simeq E[p]\otimes\chi_d$ where $\chi_d\colon G_{\mathbb Q}\to \mathbb F_p^\times$ is the quadratic character whose kernel is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{d})$. So only finitely many twists can contain a trivial subrep. When $p=2$, $\chi_d$ is always trivial, so this argument breaks down. Indeed $E_d[2]\cong E[2]$ as Galois modules.